# androidx/room/RoomProcessor has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, dagger-hilt

I started getting this error after upgrading the application dependencies to:

- Jetpack compose `1.5`
- Room `2.6.0-alpha02`
- Hilt `2.48`
- Kotlin `1.9.10`

> Execution failed for task ':module:hiltJavaCompileAppDebug'.
> androidx/room/RoomProcessor has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

I see that `55` = Java 11 and `61` = Java 17.

Should I change the Java runtime in my machine?

The app directly states in the gradle config:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

How to solve hits problem?

Comment: If you use Java 11, it is working fine?

Comment: Yes, you should change it to ```JavaVersion.VERSION_17``` because latest version of some library need it to Recent Java Version.

Comment: I also changed JavaVersion.VERSION_17 but issue cannot resolved. Then i download jdk 17 and updated gradle JDK to 17 but issue not resolved. Any other solution is available?

Answer (score 0):

Room >= `2.6.x` requires to use JDK 17. You need to update the source and target compatibility accordingly:

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
```

Depending on your build setup, you may also need:

```
kotlinOptions {
   jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

kotlin {
   jvmToolchain(17)
}
```